# C#/Excel - Get Cellname with OleDb

Tags: c#, excel

maybe someone can help me with this task:
I need to find the coordinates of a cell in Excel. But I have only the cellname.

Is it possible to get the information (coordinates, value, ...) of a cell with the OleDb - classes? with the Interop- Klass its easy. But I have to use the OleDb Klasses.

Thanks!

Comment: Is cellname something like C25, or are you referring to [named cells](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/define-named-cell-references-or-ranges-HP005201536.aspx)

Comment: Hi,
ok, i couldn't user the oledb-classes. So Im unziping the xlsx-file and reading the workbook.xml file to get alle named cells.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this exact problem a number of years ago. Not sure if it is what you are looking for but I think you can do something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM [MySheet$] WHERE ID='<YOUR CELL NAME>'"
```

Considering a connection like:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myfile.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"";
```

Comment: Hello Marcus,
thanks you for your help. 
`
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + _pathConfig + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=15;READONLY=FALSE\";");
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [MySheet$] WHERE ID ='MyName'", connection);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
`
-> Oledb-Ecxeption. A param is missing...